# PDFview in Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, pdf, google-drive-file-viewer

I want to preview PDF in google docs. I use 'http://docs.google.com/gview?url=mypdfurl'.I try to access pdf using localhost http connection. Sometime it is working fine and after some time It gives error "Whoops There was a problem to preview this document". I try many things like clear cache and cookie and also try other browser and incognito. I don't want to show this messages to my clients. So any hint or idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Jake - Community Specialist](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/gJYImnGmGAc/swMcSfKaBQAJ) on the Official Google Docs Forum

`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=` is deprecated